# Set a value from a collection to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I am trying to do some debugging and I have a collection I created from several different strings. What I would like to do is go back and set another variable equal to the second item in the collection. Is this possible? See a very simplified example below:

```
Dim TagForms As New Collection

Dim TagForm1 As String
Dim TagForm2 As String
Dim TagForm3 As String
Dim Test As String

TagForm1 = "Cat"
TagForm2 = "Dog"
TagForm3 = "Pig"

Set TagForms = New Collection

TagForms.Add TagForm1
TagForms.Add TagForm2
TagForms.Add TagForm3

Test = TagForms(2)     'This doesn't work
Set Test = TagForms(2) 'This also doesn't work
```

Comment: The first code is fine so you must be doing something else wrong. :)

Comment: Your simplified example probably doesn't match your actual code.

Comment: `set test =` for a string would not work as you set ranges and objects, but `test =` should work.

Comment: ahhh... thank you... I will try that

Comment: wait... I don't need the .item?

Comment: @XCELLGUY no, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/item-method-visual-basic-for-applications).

Comment: Also `As New` has side-effects with possible unintended consequences, and is usually best avoided.

Comment: Your code as posted (with the `Test=…` line), works fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the variable 'Test' is a string, the last code line 'Set Test = TagForms(2)' does not work.
The correct code line is 'Test = TagForms(2)'. This code returns 'Dog'